# Remove /Public from url in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

Good Day!

Hello,

Currently I was working on laravel and im new on it. I keep looking a solutions on my problem and i couldn’t find a solution on this. My laravel work is accessible already without /public in the url I fix this thru .htaccess, but it can be access also with /public in the url. Please see links below for your reference.

https://utok.ph/

https://utok.ph/public

my htaccess file

RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

Comment: Don't fix it with .htaccess. Fix your webserver config to point at the public directory. The docs have an example config for nginx: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/deployment#nginx

Comment: @ceejayoz hello sir, I will try it later. do you think it still works for the shared hosting?

Comment: That'll depend on the host.

Comment: @ceejayoz thanks bro for your quick response. I usually working on codeigniter and it was my first laravel project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.htaccess files wont work on this, what i did is i update the root directory in my server side.

instead the root will be at public_html I change it to public_html/public